# Why does the backing field of my property not change its value?

Tags: c#, properties

```
namespace tutor4
{
    class Class1
    {
        int _num = 2;
        public int num
        {
            get
            {
                return _num;
            }
            set
            {
                _num = num;
            }
        }
        public void incrementFunction()
        {
            num++;
            Console.WriteLine("The value of _num is "+ num);
        }
    }
}

namespace tutor4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Class1 class1Obj = new Class1();
            for(int i=0;i<7;i++)
                class1Obj.incrementFunction(); 
    }
}
```

I don't know why `_num` does not increase, can anyone explain please?

Comment: `set _num = num;`, because you set it to itself, set it to `value`

Comment: You are resetting the same value over and over!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your setter for `num` property is wrong.

It should **not** be

```
set
{
     _num = num;
}
```

because in this case it does nothing (sets _num back to its value since getter for `num` returns `_num` so this line is equivalent to `_num = _num`)

It should be

```
set
{
     _num = value;
}
```

MSDN explanation about [value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1khb4f8.aspx) keyword:

> The contextual keyword value is used in the set accessor in ordinary
>   property declarations. It is similar to an input parameter on a
>   method. The word value references the value that client code is
>   attempting to assign to the property

Also note: your `num` property is just simple wrapper of `_num` field of class. If you don't need some complex logic in getter and setter for this property - you can change it to [auto-implemented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx) property like this:

```
class Class1
{
    public int num { get; set;}

    public Class1
    {
        num = 2;
    }
}
```

Until C# version 6 you should assign default value to auto-implemented property in class constructor.

In C# version 6 (not yet released, should be available this summer) you will be able to assign default value to auto-implemented property in declaration:

```
public int num { get; set;} = 2;
```

Comment: You should probably explain what `value` is, since it might not be obvious to a beginner.